# complex non-linear equations in python

Tags: python

Is there any way to find the solutions of a set of non-linear complex equations in python?

I need to solve the Bethe equations of the heisenberg model (eg. equation 15 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.5627v1.pdf)

Comment: Have you tried solving it yourself? Just asking for help is not how stackoverflow works. You need to show help with an effort you made yourself (and a problem you ran into).

Comment: For this type of question, you would need to understand what computational methods would be used in the solution, then look for that tool with a google search, then try it, and then ask a question on SO.  At least in my experience solving difficult equations, it's never just "find the right software and plug in the equation".

Answer (score 3):

SciPy includes [nonlinear numerical solvers](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.nonlin.html), but you may want to consider dedicated software, such as [Wolfram Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/) especially for computation speed considerations.

If the maths is the problem at some point, consider posting to the [Math Stack Exchange website](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Sage`](http://www.sagenb.org/). Sage notebook is the browser-based interface of Sage.

Most of the scientific/ Mathematical (SciPy,NumPy,Sympy...) python libraries are integrated with Sage so you do not have to call these libraries explicitly.